# ADF Expression Builder, upper case all string fields

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am using data factory's expression builder to hash a column set:

```
md5(byNames(split($Columns,',')))
```

I would like the hash comparison of strings to be case-insensitive.  Is there a way to modify the expression above so that all string columns are hashed as upper or lower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a string function in ADF called toupper or tolower (excluding data flow)similar to Upper or lower SQL function respectively. In data flow you get the Upper and lower function.

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Hi @Nandan -- yes this is what i'm looking for but how would i apply the upper function to the entire array?

Comment: The most easy case would be to use a data flow to create a derived column wherein you can cast the column to uppercase/lowercase by upper/lower function and then use the hash function to hash the values.

Comment: To transform data inside an array, use the map() function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#map. The #item keyword represents the current item in the array. So an example of uppercasing all column names in an array would look something like this: map(columnNames(),upper(#item))